# Separeting product from post in search result

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, loop, filters, search

I am trying to separete products from posts in the search result. I can see the loop there search in both.

```
                        if( have_posts() ) {
                        while( have_posts() ) {
                            the_post();

                            echo "<p><a href='". get_the_permalink() ."'>". get_the_title() ."</a></p>";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "<h4 class='text-center'>Sorry, no content to show...</h4>";
                    }
```

How can I create one loop form products and then another for post? If I try to include prodcut loop it ignores the search and displays all the products.

Comment: anyone please? I am searching but I cant find any answer.